# How can I sign a Flex Mobile App using Android keystore?

Tags: android, apache-flex, code-signing, pkcs#12

I have just converted a native Android app to Flex 4.5 AIR, and I now need to sign it.

Does anyone know if it is possible to use the keystore that I used to sign the original Android app?

If so, how do I get a P12 out of it to use in Flex.

Thanks

G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a program called portecle to open the android keystore, change the type to a p12 and then save as a .p12 file.

Flash Builder than accepted this to sign my app.

I haven't submitted to the store yet, but looks good so far.

This would seem a much cheaper way of signing mobile AIR apps than buying certificate from the like of Thawte et. al.